# View height should change as per view width: Auto Layout

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, autolayout

Here my view width is changing as per the ratio of super view width.  Also, the height is changing as per the ratio of super view height.  However, I want to fix my height to be the same as width of view.

Specifically, something like: `view.height = view.width`

The problem is that if I am setting as per the ratio, my super view height and width then the iPhone height is greater than width.  Here are some screenshots illustrating my point below.

## iPhone Screen

[image: iPhone screen]

## iPad Screen

[image: iPad screen]

In above screens, the iPad seems good but for the iPhone height it isn't as per the ratio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution:

Steps

- First remove height constraint from view.
- Add below new constraint by code on view

  > ```
  > let equalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.imgProfile,
  >             attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Width,
  >             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
  >             toItem: self.imgProfile,
  >             attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height,
  >             multiplier: 1.0,
  >             constant: 0.0);
  >         self.imgProfile.addConstraint(equalConstraint)
  > ```

Answer (score 0):

Set the 1:1 ratio between width and height for the view, and then set proportional width between view and the superview, and adjust constraint multiplier to get the size of the view you want.

That way the view will always have the same width and height, and will change depending on the width of the superview.

Comment: for iPhone screen height and width ratio are not equal so above solution will not work .

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you want a view with the same width and height. And that width (and height) should be proportional to superview's width. Which is exactly what you'll get if you follow instructions form my answer. Regardless of the device.